# c++ convert string with dashes to integer

Tags: c++, string, integer

Using c++, if I have a string str ="0-7637-2129-8" how can I convert it into 1 big integer? 763721298
The strings will always be in that format. More examples:
1-2344-3457-8 = 1234434578
0-0002-0020-0 = 200200

Comment: If it doesn't make sense to add them together, be extremely wary of storing things like that as integer-types.  In general, store them as strings.  Better yet, as their own data type.  I find it hard to dial `1.555e+9` on my phone.  http://thedailywtf.com/Articles/Confessions-The-Phone-Number.aspx, http://thedailywtf.com/Articles/Call-Me,-Maybe.aspx, and others

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use the [erase-remove idiom](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Erase-remove_idiom) to get rid of all the `'-'` characters.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <algorithm>

int main() {
    std::string myStr = "0-7637-2129-8";
    myStr.erase(std::remove(myStr.begin(), myStr.end(), '-'), myStr.end());

    long myLong = std::atol(myStr.c_str());   // convert to long

    std::cout << "Your number is now " << myLong << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

[Working example](http://ideone.com/MBITRS)

Answer (score 2):

use:

```
str.erase(std::remove(str.begin(), str.end(), '-'), str.end());
```

and then convert to long.

Comment: @DavidSmall did you `#include <string>` and `#include <algorithm>`?

Comment: Error was due to lack of #include <algorithm>

Answer (score 2):

In a belated attempt to offer the most obfuscated and convoluted solution to the problem, I present you all with this ingenious piece of code

```
#include <locale>
#include <sstream>

...

struct dash_14 : std::numpunct<char>
{
  char do_thousands_sep() const { return '-'; }
  std::string do_grouping() const { return "\1\4"; }
};

...

std::string str = "0-7637-2129-8";
std::stringstream ss(str);
ss.imbue(std::locale(ss.getloc(), new dash_14));

unsigned long long i;
ss >> i;
```

Note that this does not require modifying the original string :)

This, of course, relies on your strings sticking to that specific format.